# Can't load XML from file

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

What is wrong here? It throws ArgumentException

```
var xmlDocument = await XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///LiveTiles/Templates.xml"));
```

Is there more simple way to load XML from file?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you put the message of the exception?

Comment: Answered in this post

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552335/how-to-open-a-packaged-file-with-winrt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows RT is a little bit special at the time of manipulating files, I highly recommend this blog entry:

http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html

Taken from the link:

> ```
> // settings
> // same as (ms-appx:///MyFolder/MyFile.txt)
> var _Folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
> _Folder = await _Folder.GetFolderAsync("MyFolder");
>
> // acquire file
> var _File = await _Folder.GetFileAsync("MyFile.txt");
> Assert.IsNotNull(_File, "Acquire File");
>
> // write content
> var _WriteThis = "Hello World";
> await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(_File, _WriteThis);
> ```

Or to simplify it a little bit more, another approach can be:

> try
>
> ```
> {
>
>     StorageFolder storageFolder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
>
>     StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("BasicData.xml");
>
>
>
>     XmlTextBlock.Text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
>
>
>
> }
>
> catch (Exception ex)
>
> {
>
>     XmlTextBlock.Text = ex.Message;
>
> }
> ```