# MediaElement throwing error

Tags: c#, mediaelement

I am trying to give a MediaElement a source when a button is clicked and then play the media, this is what I have so far:

In my XAML:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="vid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="310,193,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="Assets/Stars.mov"/>
```

In the class:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.vid.Source = new Uri("Assets/Stars.mov", UriKind.Relative);
        vid.Play();
    }
```

However I receive this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215849 for details.
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: it is related to wpf or win app?

Comment: @RahulSharma Sorry about that, Windows App

Comment: possible duplicate of [The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569720/the-given-system-uri-cannot-be-converted-into-a-windows-foundation-uri)

Answer (score 0):

I have found this error thread  please go through these :

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dbbf147c-06df-4159-b2e4-488120eb2a9e/cannot-set-mediaplayer-source-from-universal-windows-app?forum=wpf

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7bab1c6c-0baa-4edf-a3ad-95c3691e2a9a/the-given-systemuri-cannot-be-converted-into-a-windowsfoundationuri?forum=winappswithcsharp

[Programmatically set the Source of an Image (XAML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267257/programmatically-set-the-source-of-an-image-xaml)

hope this helps

Comment: I don't seem to understand the links? Could you please elaborate