# Initial image with constructor

Tags: c#

I create a class "Drink"

Drink have two variable

one is drink name, another is drink's picture

```
public class Drink
{
    public string name {get; set; }
    public Image pic {get; set; }
}
```

and initial it.

```
List<Drink> ex = new List<Drink>
{
   new Drink { name = "juice", pic = "Assets/juice.png" },
   new Drink { name = "water", pic = "Assets/water.png" }
};
```

but the pic's path is wrong, how set the picture to each?

Update:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTS2m.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean "but the pic's path is wrong", in what way is it wrong? I am betting you are getting a compiler error, if you are you could include that error as a edit to your question.

Comment: Your property is Image but you are initialising with a string.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain sorry, english isn't my native language, I want set the file to pic, and i think "Assets.." is a path, so I say "path is wrong"

Answer (score 1):

In your `Drink` class `pic` property is of type `Image` but you are assigning a `string`, it should be:

```
List<Drink> ex = new List<Drink>
{
   new Drink { name = "juice", pic = Image.FromFile("Assets/juice.png") },
   new Drink { name = "water", pic = Image.FromFile("Assets/water.png") }
};
```

Check `Image.FromFile` method on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx).

Comment: but I don't see (.FromFile)  TAT, have other way?

Comment: @pART It depends on the framework you're using, is it WinForms, WPF etc?

Comment: @pART If it's xaml it's either WPF or WinRT, check these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267257/programmatically-set-the-source-of-an-image-xaml , and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267257/programmatically-set-the-source-of-an-image-xaml

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what your asking, but you need to pass an `Image` in your initializer, not a `string`.  In the example below `Bitmap` derives from `Image`:

```
List<Drink> ex = new List<Drink>
{
   new Drink { name = "juice", pic = new Bitmap("Assets/juice.png") },
   new Drink { name = "water", pic = new Bitmap("Assets/water.png") }
};
```