# Download Image UWP (C#)

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I writing application for Windows 10 mobile.

I have Image in my XAML.

```
<Image x:Name="productimage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="146" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135"/>
```

I need to download image from URL and put it to Image

How I can do this?

Thank's with help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically set the Source of an Image (XAML)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267257/programmatically-set-the-source-of-an-image-xaml)

Comment: This is not duplicate, because those answers don't solve my problem. Anyone of this code don't work. 

And I have UWP app. @EldarDordzhiev

Comment: The question I referenced is the exact solution for your issue. UWP and Windows 8 XAML UI are basically the same UI frameworks, the solution applies to both. If the code doesn't work, then share your efforts with us. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [snipet](https://snipt.net/raw/42ef67a1a54f4146c6fec68df4aa847f/?nice)

```
System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

...

System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage imageResponse = await client.GetAsync(imageUrl);

// A memory stream where write the image data
Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccess =
new Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter writer = 
new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(randomAccess.GetOutputStreamAt(0));

// Write and save the data into the stream
writer.WriteBytes(await imageResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
await writer.StoreAsync();

// Create a Bitmap and assign it to the target Image control
Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bm =
new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
await bm.SetSourceAsync(randomAccess);
productimage.Source = bm;
```

It's not my snipet, but should work also with UWP. UWP is very similar to Windows 8.1. So you can try to search for WinRT examples

Comment: Where I need to enter URL?

Comment: imageUrl - that's string with URL

Comment: You have await, but have not async.

Comment: you need to add async predicate to method or button click event

Answer (score 1):

I found answer on my question

It's simple

```
string url = "url";
productimage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));
```

Thank's to @ Eldar Dordzhiev

Answer (score 0):

This code is in VB.Net. I guess you could read it and convert to C#. I just wanted to help. Use `Windows.Web.Http` for UWP as `System.Net.Htpp` is being depreciated.

```
Imports Windows.Web.Http
...
Dim client as New HttpClient
Dim response = Await client.GetBufferAsync(ImgUri)
stream = response.AsStream
Dim mem = New MemoryStream()
Await stream.CopyToAsync(mem)
mem.Position = 0
Dim img As New BitmapImage
img.SetSource(mem.AsRandomAccessStream)
Return img
```