# WPF - Uri to content images

Tags: c#, image, windows-runtime

I spent 1 hour on browsing internet and trying to find a way how to load Uri to content image and create an BitmapImage.

That is what I have:

```
{
    Uri x = new Uri("/Images/appbar.chevron.up.png", UriKind.Relative);
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(x);
    return x;
}
```

Images in Solution Explorer are just under project:

[image]

And each image have Build Action as Content

[image]

I'm recieving `The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215849 for details.` on creating BitmapImage, but debugger showes me that Uri was created:

[image]

Please tell me, how can I load selected image?

Comment: Did you search for the exception? here is it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569720/the-given-system-uri-cannot-be-converted-into-a-windows-foundation-uri

Comment: Yes, I tried opion with `ms-appx:`. It doesn't work as well.

Comment: Doesn't work never explains anything. Explain what happens. Any exception? error?

Comment: Are you using the bitmap as the content of a control? If so, can you set this in the Xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, to load the image from your app package you'll use the ms-appx protocol. See the [URI schemes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj655406.aspx) documentation on MSDN

```
Uri x = new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/appbar.chevron.up.png");
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(x);
```

Then you'll want to return the BitmapImage rather than the URI to your caller:

```
return bi; // not: return x;
```

Or set it on an Image control. The BitmapImage is just data and doesn't show up on its own.

img.SetSource(bi);

Where img is created in your Xaml:

Guessing from the names of the images you are trying to set them in appbar buttons. For that you can use the Segoe UI Symbol font instead of loading images:

```
<AppBarButton>
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Glyph="&#57361;"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
<AppBarButton>
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Glyph="&#57360;"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
```

Or if you want to set AppBarButtons to images in xaml:

```
<AppBarButton>
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <BitmapIcon UriSource="Images/appbar.chevron.up.png"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
<AppBarButton>
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <BitmapIcon UriSource="Images/appbar.chevron.down.png"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how content and resources work in WinRT, but in WPF, "Content" items must be copied to the output directory. They get added to the manifest, but the files themselves are not embedded.

If you want to embed the file, use a build action of "Resource" (it's possible that WinRT does not even support "Content"--I have never used it).  It also appears that you need to create an `Absolute` URI with `ms-appx:` scheme.